# Laravel load middleware in routes under condition

Tags: laravel, caching, middleware

I have a route files for my api and im using [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-responsecache) package to cache the whole response.

`routes/api.php`

```
<?php

Route::get('/types', 'TypeController@indexType')->middleware('cacheResponse:600');
```

This works fine but i need to skip this middleware loading when i have a specific header in the request so i make this extra middleware

`conditionalCacheResponse.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ConditionalCacheResponse
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (request()->header('Draft') != true) {
            $this->middleware('cacheResponse:3600');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and setup like this

`routes/api.php`

```
<?php

Route::get('/types', 'TypeController@indexType')->middleware('conditionalCacheResponse');
```

But is not working, im not sure if i can append a middleware in this way.

Comment: Can you not just do the conditional check inside the `handle()` method of your `cacheResponse` middleware? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52754969/2929617

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this, one way would be to use the `handle()` method of the HttpKernel to unset the `CacheResponse` middleware based on a check of the request header.

So in `app/Http/Kernel.php`, add this method:

```
public function handle($request)
{
    if ($request->header('Draft')) {
        if (($key = array_search('Spatie\ResponseCache\Middlewares\CacheResponse', $this->middleware)) !== false) {
            unset($this->middleware[$key]);
        }
    }
    return parent::handle($request);
}
```

I haven't checked this is working, but it should do the job.