# 1 route, 2 different views Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes

I'm trying to accomplish what facebook does

When you go to facebook, you're greeted with the login page at the / route

Once logged in, you're now greeted with the newsfeed, but still at the / route

I also need to be able to attach the verified middleware to the auth side

I tried making a HomeController and putting:

```
if(Auth::check()) {
//return dashboard view
}else{
//return guest view
}
```

This works, but I have no way to force email verification or any other middlewares other than the general auth middleware. If I attach the verified auth on the / route, it obviously forces that for both guest and auth

Thank you

Comment: Why can't your middleware just return a view then?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754279/run-a-middleware-on-condition-laravel

Comment: @Jaquarh I tried that but I'm not able to check if the email is verified so it shows the dashboard without forcing email verification. I supposed I can just allow the dashboard to be shown with a notice that their email isn't verified (instead of forcing them to a view file)

Comment: @Jaquarh I figured it out, I did the following in the controller:

if(Auth::user()->email_verified_at == null){
return view('auth.verify-email');
}

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to do similar, I found out I can achieve this by putting the following line into the HomeController:

```
if(Auth::user()->email_verified_at == null){
return view('auth.verify-email');
}
```

Comment: redirect them to the route where they can verify